# Branching dialogs/forms based on response in MS Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

We're experimenting with the MS Bot Framework and haven't quite worked out how to do this scenario:

We have a LUIS Dialog (type `<object>`), which is working correctly and is trained properly.  To use the common sandwich example, the basics of what LUIS intent is looking for is the user asking for the status of an order.  If the order number was provided in the question ("What is the status of order 1234?"), then the LUIS dialog does the lookup and reports the status directly (which is all currently working).

However, if the user just triggers the intent without providing the order number ("I'd like to look up the status of an order."), I'd like to launch another dialog/form to ask the user if they'd like to look up the order by address or order number, and then do the appropriate DB lookup based on how they answer.

I'm just not sure how to configure the Form/Dialog (or even which is best in this case) to do a different lookup based on if they choose address or number lookup.

Here's the intent so far:

```
private readonly BuildFormDelegate<OrderStatusDialog> OrderStatusDelegate;

[LuisIntent(nameof(LuisIntents.OrderStatus))]
public async Task OrderStatus(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    // Order number(s) were provided
    if (result.Entities.Any(Entity => Entity.Type == nameof(LuisEntityTypes.OrderNumber)))
    {
        // Loop in case they asked about multiple orders
        foreach (var entity in result.Entities.Where(Entity => Entity.Type == nameof(LuisEntityTypes.OrderNumber)))
        {
            var orderNum = entity.Entity;

            // Call webservice to check status
            var request = new RestRequest(Properties.Settings.Default.GetOrderByNum, Method.GET);
            request.AddUrlSegment("num", orderNum);
            var response = await RestHelper.SendRestRequestAsync(request);

            var parsedResponse = JObject.Parse(response);

            if ((bool)parsedResponse["errored"])
            {
                await context.PostAsync((string)parsedResponse["errMsg"]);
                continue;
            }

            // Grab status from returned JSON
            var status = parsedResponse["orderStatus"].ToString();

            await context.PostAsync($"The status of order {orderNum} is {status}");
        }

        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
    // Order number was not provided
    else
    {
        var orderStatusForm = new FormDialog<OrderStatusDialog>(new OrderStatusDialog(), OrderStatusDelegate,
            FormOptions.PromptInStart);
        context.Call<OrderStatusDialog>(orderStatusForm, CallBack);
    }
}

private async Task CallBack(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

And the form:

```
public enum OrderStatusLookupOptions
{
    Address,
    OrderNumber
}

[Serializable]
public class OrderStatusDialog
{
    public OrderStatusLookupOptions? LookupOption;

    public static IForm<OrderStatusDialog> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<OrderStatusDialog>()
            .Message("In order to look up the status of a order, we will first need either the order number or your delivery address.")
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FormFlow route is a valid option. What is missing in your form flow is asking for the address/order number after the lookup option is selected.

What you can do in that case is adding two more fields to the `OrderStatusDialog` class: `OrderNumber` and `DeliveryAddress`.

Then you need to use the selected `OrderStatusLookupOptions` to activate/deactivate the next field.

The code, from the top of my head, would be something like:

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderStatusDialog
{
    public OrderStatusLookupOptions? LookupOption;

    public int OrderNumber;

    public string DeliveryAddress

    public static IForm<OrderStatusDialog> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<OrderStatusDialog>()
            .Message("In order to look up the status of a order, we will first need either the order number or your delivery address.")
            .Field(nameof(OrderStatusDialog.LookupOption))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<OrderStatusDialog>(nameof(OrderStatusDialog.OrderNumber))
                .SetActive(state => state.LookupOption == OrderStatusLookupOptions.OrderNumber))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<OrderStatusDialog>(nameof(OrderStatusDialog.DeliveryAddress))
                .SetActive(state => state.LookupOption == OrderStatusLookupOptions.Address))
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Then on your Callback method you will receive the form filled and you can do the DB lookup.

Alternatively, you can just use PromptDialogs and guide the user through the same experience. Take a look to the [MultiDialogs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs) sample to see the different alternatives.

I added a working sample on this [here](https://github.com/ejadib/FormFlowBranchBasedOnResponse).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sure its just an issue of you doing it off memory, but with the code above it always asks for both (also, the .Message() is not shown for some reason).

Comment: Mmm I just tried this and it's working fine. There was a missing parameter after the Field LookupOption that was preventing the code to compile... but after fixing that (I edited the post) everything seems to be working ok, including the message. What version of BotBuilder r u using?

Comment: Looks like I'm on 3.5.5

Comment: Yes, me too. I opened the MultiDialogs sample and change the HotelsQuery class to be your OrderStatusDialog and then I changed the creation of the form to in the BuildHotelsForm of the HotelsDialog class to be the code in the answer. Then I replaced some failing references, and that's how I tested this is working as expected.

Comment: I added a working sample on https://github.com/ejadib/FormFlowBranchBasedOnResponse

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile! I downloaded your sample and ran as is, and it still asks for both.  I picked the second option first, it correctly asks me for input, and then asks me for the 1st option.  I am seeing the .Message() now though

Comment: Unbelievable!! Are you testing this in the Emulator or where? Here are the images showing what I'm seeing: [Address Flow](http://picbin.org/o/1342) and [Order Flow](http://picbin.org/o/1343)

Comment: We are seeing the same thing I think... but this is an or option, if the user picks Order Number, I would expect that it not ask about the address at all, and your picture for Order flow is what I'm seeing.  I would thought it wouldn't ask about Order Delivery Address at all in an order number choice and vice versa..

Comment: ? It's not asking the Delivery Address, is just showing the results of the form, that's why is showing bot the Order Number and the Order Address values. They are being shown in the [callback](https://github.com/ejadib/FormFlowBranchBasedOnResponse/blob/master/RootDialog.cs#L29). Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, your sample works as expected.... Still having mine ask for both and not send the .Message... could it be because your sample is directly called, and mine is going from a LUIS Dialog as the root dialog and launching the status dialog from the LUIS dialog?  Here's how I invoke it: `var orderStatusForm = new FormDialog<OrderStatusDialog>(new OrderStatusDialog(), OrderStatusDelegate,FormOptions.PromptInStart);` and `context.Call<OrderStatusDialog>(orderStatusForm, CallBack);`

Comment: Who is filling the OrderStatusDelegate and with what values? Why are not using directly the BuildForm method? (see my code)

Comment: Actually that could be the problem I think. Just remove the delegate and use the BuildForm method..

Comment: Yep! That was it.  Thanks!